# List View Sorting

Tags: list-view

I have a list of standard list views for `Opportunity`, like 'All Opportunities', 'My Opportunities' etc.
For some reason sorting sign for 'Opportunity Name' and 'Customer Name' is missing.
Are there some specific settings or reasons for that?

Comment: are these fields Shield-encrypted?

Comment: looks like that. thanks for a tip, looks like it is a problem

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are Shield Platform-encrypted, they can not be sorted in list views. [From the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_considerations_general.htm&type=5):

> **Reports, Dashboards, and List Views**

> Report charts and dashboard components that display encrypted field values might be cached unencrypted.

> You **can’t sort records in list views** by fields that contain encrypted data.

Note also that SOQL ORDER BY may not be used on platform-encrypted fields